# Como retirar alerta de "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um arquivo `.js` no meu site onde eu coloco alguns efeitos e tudo mais. O problema é que está acusando um alerta de **"Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"** e não sei o que é.

É um erro de código? Pois todos os comandos e efeitos são executados normalmente.

Meu `jQuery` é este:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    //======================================================
    // Ajuste automático da altura do background do header
    var header = jQuery('#header'),
        bg = jQuery('#bg'),
        altura_janela = jQuery(window).height(),
        altura_final = altura_janela - 125;

        bg.css({ 'height': altura_final+'px' });


    //======================================================
    // Menu fixo
    var headerBottom = 200;
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
            var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop(), menufixo = jQuery("#menu-fixo");
            if (scrollTop > headerBottom) {
                if (menufixo.is(":visible") == false) {
                    menufixo.fadeIn(300);
                }
            } else {
                if (menufixo.is(":visible")) {
                    menufixo.fadeOut(300);
                }
            }
    });


    //======================================================
    // Botão voltar ao topo
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrollTop2 = jQuery(window).scrollTop(), backtop = jQuery("#back-top");
        if (scrollTop2 > 500) {
             if (backtop.is(":visible") == false) {
                  backtop.fadeIn(200);
             }
        } else {
             if (backtop.is(":visible")) {
                  backtop.fadeOut(100);
             }
        }
    });


    //======================================================
    // Efeito âncoras
    jQuery('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;

    if (target == '') { e.preventDefault(); }
    else if (target == '#topo') { 
        jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({ 'scrollTop': 0 }, 900, 'swing');
    }
    else if (target == "#maisconteudo") {
        jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({ 'scrollTop': 700 }, 900, 'swing');
    }
    else {
        var Starget = jQuery(target),
            alturadolink = Starget.offset().top,
            alturaefeito = (alturadolink - 70);

        jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({ 'scrollTop': alturaefeito }, 900, 'swing');
    }

    });


    //======================================================
    // Efeito seta que mexe
    var imgSETABAIXO = jQuery('#seta');
    jQuery(function() {
       function setaShake() {
          if (imgSETABAIXO.css('display') != 'none') {
              imgSETABAIXO.animate({"padding":"30px 0"},600).animate({"padding":"24px 0"},400);
              setTimeout(setaShake(),1500);
          }
       }
       setaShake();
    });


    //======================================================
    // Carousel de notícias
    var carousel = jQuery('#carousel');
    carousel.cycle({
        fx: 'carousel',
        carouselVisible: '3',
        next: '.carousel-next',
        prev: '.carousel-prev',
        slides: '> .carousel-post',
        timeout: '20000',
        pager: '.carousel-pager',
        pagerTemplate: '<a href="#">A</a>'
    });

});
```

Acredito que o problema esteja neste efeito: ([ver online](http://jsfiddle.net/k2pjjf69/))

```
//======================================================
// Efeito seta que mexe
var imgSETABAIXO = jQuery('#seta');
jQuery(function() {
   function setaShake() {
      if (imgSETABAIXO.css('display') != 'none') {
          imgSETABAIXO.animate({"padding":"30px 0"},600).animate({"padding":"24px 0"},400);
          setTimeout(setaShake(),1500);
      }
   }
   setaShake();
});
```

É um efeito que faz uma seta ficar se movendo para baixo e para cima, infinitamente.

O que pode ser?
Obrigado.

Comment: Tem como voce upar seu código no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Claro, fiz somente da seta: http://jsfiddle.net/k2pjjf69/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removi o `setTimeout` que estava causando o problema e adicionei setInterval para o movimento ficar se repetindo e ficou assim:

```
//======================================================
// Efeito seta que mexe
var imgSETABAIXO = $('#seta');
$(function() {

   function setaShake() {
      if (imgSETABAIXO.css('display') != 'none') {
          imgSETABAIXO.animate({"padding":"30px 0"},600).animate({"padding":"24px 0"},400);         
      }  
   }
   setaShake();
   setInterval(setaShake,1100);     
});
```

O **jQuery** considera o `setTimeout` como um cara que só vai fazer determinado processo uma vez, pois estava excedendo o limite esperado e quando voce tentou referenciar o metodo novamente voce o chamou, bastava retirar os parenteses que funcionaria também, ficaria assim:

```
//======================================================

    // Efeito seta que mexe
    var imgSETABAIXO = $('#seta');
    $(function() {
       function setaShake() {
          if (imgSETABAIXO.css('display') != 'none') {
              imgSETABAIXO.animate({"padding":"30px 0"},600).animate({"padding":"24px 0"},400);
              setTimeout(setaShake,1500);
          }
       }
       setaShake();
    });
```

Fonte: https://rogeriolino.wordpress.com/2006/12/19/javascript-settimeout-e-setinterval/

Comment: Funcionou! Pelo menos não está mais mostrando o aviso. Muito obrigado! Só mais uma coisa... antes de usar o setTimeout, eu usei um .delay(1500) no final da linha do animate, e também alertou. Sabe por que?

Comment: Provavelmente porque voce ainda estava chamando o metodo, não tenho certeza, somente vendo o código